# Installing jenkins in linux - import read failed(-1)

Tags: linux, http, jenkins, proxy

I am trying to install the Jenkins in linux machine :
    steps followed :

```
1> wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/jenkins.repo http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/redhat-stable/jenkins.repo
2 >rpm --import https://jenkins-ci.org/redhat/jenkins-ci.org.key
```

While importing the key I am getting

```
error: https://jenkins-ci.org/redhat/jenkins-ci.org.key: import read failed(-1).
```

Please help me in resolving this issue .

```
 vi  /etc/yum.repos.d/jenkins.repo
[jenkins]
name=Jenkins-stable
baseurl=http://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable
gpgcheck=1
```

Answer (score 10):

I managed to get it working for me but I had to change the following for the import:

```
sudo wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/jenkins.repo http://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.repo
sudo rpm --import http://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.io.key
sudo yum install jenkins
```

Answer (score 3):

Had this same issue and finally resolved it by using wget to download the key locally and then was able to import.  When using wget, had to use the flag to not check certificate...

At first got the following errors when using wget:

> ERROR: cannot verify jenkins-ci.org's certificate, issued by `/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3':
>     Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
>   ERROR: certificate common name`accounts.jenkins.io' doesn't match requested host name `jenkins-ci.org'.
>   To connect to jenkins-ci.org insecurely, use`--no-check-certificate'.

So just use the `--no-check-certificate` option with wget and then import it. This worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

```
wget -q -o - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian/jenkins.io.key | sudo apt-key add -

sudo sh -c 'echo deb http://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list'

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install jenkins
```

source: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/

Comment: You can and should format your code using the {} button.